# C : pthread : value doesn't stay same in thread parameter

Tags: c, pthreads

I try to test `Linux pthread`. I create multithread, in each thread, I pass some parameters through `thread_arg struct`. Before I pass to thread function, I print out, everything works fine. When this parameter passes to thread function, I print out again, I see that value in parameters doesn't stay as before.

Here is my code :

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct  {
    int paramA;
    int paramB;
} thread_arg;

void* message(void* argObj) {
    thread_arg* arg = (thread_arg*) argObj;
    printf("Test2: %d &&& %d\n", arg->paramA, arg->paramB);
    return NULL;
}

void Func(int id, int num) {
    // run num-th thread.
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        // start a new thread
        pthread_t thread;
        // printf("thread with: %d and %d\n", id, i);
        // thread_arg arg = {.studentId = id, .questionId = i};
        thread_arg arg;
        arg.paramA = id;
        arg.paramB = i;
        printf("test 1: %d &&& %d\n", arg.paramA, arg.paramB);
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &message, &arg);
    }
}

int main() {
    int i;
  for(i=0;i<1;i++) {
    Func(i, 3);    
  } 
  while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is :

```
test 1: 0 &&& 1  // normal
test 1: 0 &&& 2  // normal
test 1: 0 &&& 3  // normal
Test2: 0 &&& 3   // strange error
Test2: 0 &&& 3   // strange error
Test2: 0 &&& 3   // strange error
```

It's so strange, because three lines on test 2 should be contains all number 1 2 and 3.

I cannot explain why this situation happen. Please explain for me.

Thanks :)

Comment: At the end of your for loop `arg` is destroyed as it goes out of scope. You need to declare it dynamically so the pointer you pass to `message` will still be valid when it runs that print statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new thread with `pthread_create()`, you pass the *address* of the arguments as `&arg`. This is just a pointer, and a pointer is all that your thread receives. When your `Func()` code loops around to start another thread, your `arg` variable goes out of scope and is destroyed. The memory previously occupied by `arg` is used for something else (probably the `arg` created for the next iteration of the loop).

One way to solve this is to allocate `thread_arg *parg = (thread_arg *) malloc(sizeof thread_arg);` and pass `parg` (a pointer) to `pthread_create()`. Don't forget to free the arguments within the thread after you're done with them.

Comment: since he isn't using c++, he would have to use malloc()

Comment: @GregHewgill oh. thanks. I understand it and can fix it now :) I try above code, base on some code samples when I google. so this likes a "bug" or not a well-pattern, that almost all tutorials about pthread do :D

Comment: @GregHewgill can you tell me, because I create new thread in loop. as you say, I should free memory of arguments after done, so do I need an array of arguments for this purpose ? Or have another solution ? Thanks :)

Comment: It is not necessary to create an array. You can `malloc()` in one thread, pass the pointer to another thread, and `free()` in the second thread. Another solution would be to create an array of `thread_arg` and pass a different address to each thread, but you still have to make sure that the array stays valid until all threads have read what they need from it.

Comment: thanks :) I understand it. I'm come from Java World (that already has  garbarage collector) so that memory management doesn't familiar with me :D